# csvhelper everything get written in one column in Excel

Tags: c#, excel, csv, csvhelper

I'm trying to use csvhelper to create my csv file by following some tutorials but all my data get written in only one column. This is my code:

**EDITED** As I understood from the comments, the problem is with excel reading the csv files. I found some solution that I can fix this problem by making some changes in Excel setting, in that case my question is: is there anyway to address this issue from my code, that it won't require any changes in Excel setting to be able to read csv files properly?

```
    public void CreateCSVFile()
    {
        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(@"countrylistoutput.csv"))
        {
            var writer = new CsvWriter(sw);
            using (var dt = ExportToCSV())
            {
                foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
                {
                    writer.WriteField(column.ColumnName);
                }
                writer.NextRecord();

                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    for (var i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
                    {
                        writer.WriteField(row[i]);
                    }
                    writer.NextRecord();
                }
            }
        }


    }
```

I don't get what I'm doing wrong, I would appreciate it if anyone could help me with this issue.

And here is how I tried to feed the data:

```
    public System.Data.DataTable ExportToCSV()
    {
        System.Data.DataTable table = new System.Data.DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Sex", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Subject1", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("Subject2", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("Subject3", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("Subject4", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("Subject5", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("Subject6", typeof(int));
        table.Rows.Add(1, "Amar", "M", 78, 59, 72, 95, 83, 77);
        table.Rows.Add(2, "Mohit", "M", 76, 65, 85, 87, 72, 90);
        table.Rows.Add(3, "Garima", "F", 77, 73, 83, 64, 86, 63);
        table.Rows.Add(4, "jyoti", "F", 55, 77, 85, 69, 70, 86);
        table.Rows.Add(5, "Avinash", "M", 87, 73, 69, 75, 67, 81);
        table.Rows.Add(6, "Devesh", "M", 92, 87, 78, 73, 75, 72);
        return table;
    }
}
```

[screenshot of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mH4xf.png)

Thanks

Comment: There's nothing wrong. You *imported* the file in Excel using `;` as the list separator instead of `,`.

Comment: When you double click on a CSV file, Excel *imports* it using your locale's list separator. In locales where `,` is the decimal separator, the list separator is `;`. Either set a different list separator when exporting, or use `File > Open` or `Data > Insert` to import the file with your own settings

Comment: On the other hand, if you want to read the file in Excel, use EPPlus to create a real `xlsx` file with eg `sheet.LoadFromDataTable(dt)`

Comment: Hi Panagiotis,
I added the method that shows how I feed the data as well, so maybe the correct way to ask the question is, how can I feed my data that the result can be open by excel as well (not only excel)

Comment: when You modify question add at least mark update: or similar. Hard to discus with changing questions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That happens when Excel doesn't use commas as the field separator (it depends on Excel's locale). The solution for Excel specifically is to add a special `sep=,` line at the top of the file, above any headers. For example:

```cs
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(outputFilePath))
{
    streamWriter.WriteLine("sep=,"); // make Excel use comma as field separator
    using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(streamWriter))
    {
        csvWriter.WriteField("field A");
        csvWriter.WriteField("field B");
        csvWriter.NextRecord();
    }
}
```

That will fix the problem in Excel, but cause problems in other spreadsheet apps. You can support both by making that `sep=,` line conditional on the intended format. Here's how that might look in a web UI:
[image: download button with 'csv' and 'csv for excel' options]

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your CSV looks like

```
a,b,c
d,e,f
```

you need to make it

```
"a","b","c"
"d","e","f"
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54027009/9306125