# CsvHelper wrap all values with quotes

Tags: csv, quotes, streamwriter, csvhelper

I am using CsvHelper I need to wrap all values with quotes.
Is  that possible?

Data =  is a List

```
 using (StreamWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(path))
 {
     textWriter.BaseStream.Write(p, 0, p.Length);
     // var dt = new DataTable();
     var csv = new CsvWriter(textWriter);
     csv.WriteRecords(Data);
     textWriter.Flush();
     textWriter.Close();
 }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There is a config value called `ShouldQuote` where you can determine on a field level if it should be quoted.

```
void Main()
{
    var records = new List<Foo>
    {
        new Foo { Id = 1, Name = "one" },
        new Foo { Id = 2, Name = "two" },
    };

    using (var writer = new StringWriter())
    using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer))
    {
        csv.Configuration.ShouldQuote = (field, context) => true;
        csv.WriteRecords(records);

        writer.ToString().Dump();
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

```
"Id","Name"
"1","one"
"2","two"
```

Comment: Thanks! Can it work with CsvReader from your tool?

Comment: @Stu_Dent Not sure what you mean.

Comment: This seems to be outdated. Use the answer from @Nahue Gonzalez.

Answer (score 19):

From version 25.0.0 up to the date, the way of doing it is:

```
var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
{
    ShouldQuote = args => true
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Just need to add a configuration object. like this

```
CsvHelper.Configuration.CsvConfiguration config = new CsvHelper.Configuration.CsvConfiguration();
               config.QuoteAllFields = true;
                var csv = new CsvWriter(textWriter, config);
```